# I can't find Generate local resource from tools menu in visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net

I'm in design view (markup) at webpage. I can't find "Generate Local Resource" from my tools menu. Can any one tell me how to enable this tool.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ensure you are viewing the "Design" or "Split" tab, not the "Source" tab when viewing the aspx or ascx file. Additionally, this post may help, which states in part,

"If you are using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, this walkthrough assumes that you selected the Web Development collection of settings the first time that you started Microsoft Visual Studio 2010."

[How to generate local resources in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010](http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=1433)

Comment: The fact that  actually need to have the WYSIWYG active is silly, but you were really helpful thank you for the information!

Answer (score 3):

In addition, this may also be usefull to know that VS.net Web *Express* editions (at least, in 2012 Web Express) do not implement this functionality.

Or it is really, really hidden and not in the same menu as it used to be because I just don't find it at all!

Here are all options of `Tools` Menu:

[image: All available options]

Comment: I'm using 2012 Web Express, I have checked Choose Toolbox Items but see Localisation is already installed - So I couldn't add an option for it. Could you able to add ? What did you select ? Currently I have only an option for adding Global Resource (Add New Item -> Resource File, but this adds Global Resource). I couldn't add Local Resource.

Comment: Nah, but in fact,  I was just showing this image to let other see what is shown when hovering "TOOLS" menu from `VS.net Web Express 2012`. When not in Express, you'll see the Generate Local Resource Button. Otherwize, you'll have to create it manually.

Comment: Hm okey, thank you. In fact I have add by this option, but it showned as disabled. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Visual Studio Community and still not being able to find the option in Tools, go to **Tools > Options > Web Forms Designer > General** and switch to **Legacy Web Forms designer**. Restart and check again. This solved it for me.