# I can't find Generate local resource from tools menu in visual studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013

When I'm in design view(markup) of a web page, I can't find the `Generate Local Resource` from my tools menu. Can anyone tell me how to enable this tool?

[image]

Comment: Related: [I can't find Generate local resource from tools menu in visual studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7962773/464709). The same solution may apply.

Comment: "Design" tab already viewing according to this image but genrate local resource option is not come.
Please give me proper solution.

Comment: I was referring to the "select the Web Development collection of settings the first time you start Visual Studio" part of the answer.